# Using "npm install" for development environment in Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I'm trying to work on a ReactJS project for development purposes in Docker,  and this project will be shared across a team.

However, I'm having trouble understanding how this works because I want to volume share my `app` directory into the container, but it seems I have to copy `package.json` into the container to `npm install` and therefore run `nom run start`

my directory structure is:

```
app/
  src/
  public/
  node_modules/
  package.json
docker/ 
  admin/
    dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.8.0

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  admin:
    build:
      context: ./docker/admin
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    image: project/admin
    volumes:
     - ./app:/app
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

So the problem is: when the dockerfile runs, `npm install` fails because the volume sharing from the `docker-compose` hasn't happened yet, so it thinks there's no `package.json`.  So it sounds like I have to copy `package.json` into the container, which isn't ideal for development as far as making changes.

Furthermore, I believe you can only `COPY` files into the container from within the same directory as the dockerfile, which would mean I'd have to move the dockerfile to the root of the project.  I don't love this idea because I'll have other containers in this project as well, and they'll need dockerfiles too.

Is there better solution for handling Node development from within Docker?  Essentially, I'm looking to make the "up and running" process as simple as possible for other devs on the team.

Answer (score 1):

During development you need:

- rebuild your frontend
- restart you Node.js application
- rerun you tests
- debug your code
- etc

If you will try put you files to Docker container during development, you will have overhead on development process. You computer and developer will spend more time, then with native usage node.js

**That why wrapping Node.js in Docker during development is bad practice.**

When you need Docker during development?

- setup Developer/CI/QA environments with external dependency like MongoDB, Redis, etc. `docker-compose` is the best solution rights now.
- making deliverable artifact. `Dockerfile` + `.dockerignore` will describe how make your artifact

Comment: Hm interesting, i wasn't aware that this wasn't a preferred practice.  Is that documented anywhere else in the Node or Docker community?

Comment: I saw it several times in conference/meetup videos, but I don't remember any document about this. It's just common sense, not part of documemtation.